# Is it possible to increase Database storage in Neo4j Aura

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-aura

Planning to subscribe Aura cloud managed services with memory 4GB, 0.8 CPU and 8 GB storage plan.

1. But the storage is not enough. Is it possible to increase the storage in this plan?
2. How many core of CPUs in this plan if its mentioned as 0.8 CPU?

Answer (score 0):

The Aura [pricing structure](https://neo4j.com/cloud/aura/#pricing) is very simple. You can increase storage (or memory or CPU) by paying for a higher-priced tier. *Of course, you can contact Neo4j directly to ask if they have any other options.*

`0.8 CPU` means that you get the equivalent of 80% of a single core.

You can get more details from the Aura [knowledge base](https://aura.support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us) and [developer guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/aura-cloud-dbaas/).